# CSS issue with header and nav list - Not aligning

Tags: html, css

This is my first time using stackoverflow and first time attempt at developing a webpage *please don't lynch me*. I am a network engineer by trade trying my hand at some coding.

I'm trying to build a basic portfolio webpage. header, nav, image,content and footer. Nothing too fancy. I am having some issues getting my header to line up with my nav. Was ok before I change the header text 'Terry' to the oleo font.If I keep it as default it lines up with the nav text.

How do I resolve this so my NAv shows in my header (it looks like its pushed down)? 
Would I have been better having two divs side by side, (as I have done with a left column and right column directly below?
Is it something to do with the use of floats?

Any advice would be great!

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: green;
}

#nav li {
  float: right;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navli {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#banner {}

#leftcolumn {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 75%;
  float: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 75%;
  float: right;
}

#header {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  font: 200 100px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#footer {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="C:\Users\nick.szilagyi\Desktop\PROJECT\JS\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\nick.szilagyi\Desktop\PROJECT\JS\jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom\jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    Terry
    <div id="nav">
      <ul class="navli">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="leftcolumn">left</div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">right</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The simplest thing might be to set `.nav` to `display: inline;`. That being said I would look at using [**`flexbox`**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties). You'll also have issues with a set font size in the header and the header itself being a percentage height.

Comment: I would recommend you to start with Bootstrap. You are struggling with responsive-design.

Comment: Wow, I hope all, not just new, users will ask questions like this - Proper example, clear description. Everything is fine. Please take a look at the answers and consider accepting one of them it if you find it helpful. Good luck :)

Comment: This posts's comments are being discussed [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348824/5827958). @ShawnWhinnery

Comment: Just to be clear: site rules require your code be in the question itself, just as you did here. Creating an example at a fiddle/bin site would be in addition to what you did here, not instead of.

Comment: What  I can't quite work out though is why my nav items are purple?

Comment: Also thank you, i'll stick to what I did and add a fiddlebin as well. It's helping me after all so i don't mind

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;` on the header to push the name and nav to the sides and center them vertically while keeping them on the same line. Then no need to float your nav or the nav li's, so I used `display: inline-block` on the nav li's instead and re-ordered them so they are in the same order in the code as they display on the page.

You should probably also remove the `height: 20%` on the header and let it be it's natural height, but you didn't ask about that so I didn't change it.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: green;
}

#nav li {
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navli {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#banner {}

#leftcolumn {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 75%;
  float: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 75%;
  float: right;
}

#header {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  font: 200 100px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheetterry.css' />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="C:\Users\nick.szilagyi\Desktop\PROJECT\JS\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">
      <div>Terry</div>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul class="navli">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My research</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Teaching</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leftcolumn">left</div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">right</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? :

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: green;
}

#nav li {
  float: right;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navli {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#banner {}

#leftcolumn {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 75%;
  float: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 75%;
  float: right;
}

#header {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  font: 200 100px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#footer {
  background-color: #6495ed;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="C:\Users\nick.szilagyi\Desktop\PROJECT\JS\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\nick.szilagyi\Desktop\PROJECT\JS\jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom\jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    Terry
    <div id="nav">
      <ul class="navli">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="leftcolumn">left</div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">right</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, not quite in line with the header but closer to what I am trying to acheive